# Clarification on sarcasm/type of personality-stumped

Tags: meaning

I am hoping to get some help. I have always been told that I am the most sarcastic person people have ever met. After 20 years, I decided to dive a little deeper to see if I fit the definition. It turns out I do not fit the definition of sarcastic. I also don't fit any of the others either, such as: sardonic, dry sense of humor, snarky, etc.

I am very direct but not in a bossy way. For instance, when a co-worker snaps at me because of their mood, I will bring attention to it but not in an ugly way. An example:

> ummmmm.....so not sure what's going on with allll THAT, but Ima need you to calm yourself before talking to me like that.

This, in turn, makes the co-worker laugh and recognize the way it came across. I always am direct, but I am direct in a way that makes others laugh and is not offensive.

I have been told many, many times that I say and get away with saying things that most would never even think of saying because of my personality. If others were to say the things I say, there would be a fight or trouble. However, when I say it, people laugh and "know my personality."

I would like to know what this would be called. I am never rude and never make someone feel bad. In fact, quite the opposite; those that are in a fowl mood usually lighten up.

This is how I am about 95% of the time. Other times (when I feel strongly about my position), I am direct and dead serious (but still not ugly).

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!
A

Comment: It's called diplomacy/ tact.

Comment: Winston S. Churchill — 'Diplomacy is the art of telling people to go to hell in such a way that they ask for directions.'

Comment: You need to get health insurance so you could afford to go to a formally trained therapist. We are all quacks here, unqualified to treat your symptoms.

Comment: You might be described as being "simpatico" (It's used in the US, am I right?) or *charming*. But without knowing you it's impossible to say for certain. Anyone who is *simpatico* can get away with almost anything in life because people find them so spontaneous, friendly and maybe even sincere.

Comment: "I have always been told that I am the most sarcastic person people have ever met."  Impossible!  I'm the most sarcastic person alive.

Comment: (But this is not the Psychology SE site.  You're probably barking up the wrong stack.)

Comment: Yes, I figured I was in the wrong area. However, this site is the one that continuously popped up. So, clearly, Google seems to think this is where I should be! I appreciate the attempt to help;I now have other words to research. Additionally, I am going to consider a "shrink" to discuss my "symptoms." Mari-Lou,thank you. Hot licks, bless your heart!! Thanks again for the help ~well, off to the shrink...

Comment: Wait, do you really use "Ima" in everyday speech?

Comment: Actually, Mr Lister, I do! Is that bad? 

Comment: if you are in any way sarcastic, stop being so as it is incredibly old-fashioned and annoying.

Answer (score 2):

The phrase I would use for the combination of traits you describe is "disarmingly direct." The "direct" part you note yourself (four times) in the course of stating the question. But evidently the thing that sets your directness apart from, say, Alceste's (in Molière's [*The Misanthrope*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Misanthrope)) is that you wield it in a way that lowers hackles instead of raising them. This gift, I think, is aptly characterized as being "disarming." Hence, "disarmingly direct."

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Sven! By the way, if I haven't mentioned it before, I'm very direct! :)

Comment: the answer is correct - so tick it.

Answer (score 1):

You're ***candid***.

Synonyms include *forthright* and *frank*.

But *candid* is what you describe because it connotes sincerity and not bluntness, which many of the synonyms do imply.  It's also not perceived as a negative personality trait.

Answer (score 0):

I’ve been made to think I was sarcastic also until a couple of days ago I learned about the word candid. I feel that you may be candid too. It describes our personality to a “T”. Hope that helps.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/417390)